# Move VStack at the top of the page swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, vstack

I want to create a top bar and my code looks like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Bar()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct Bar: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Community").comfortaa(weight: .bold, size: 20).foregroundColor(.therameBlack)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill").font(.headline).foregroundColor(.therameBlack)
                }
            }
        }.padding(.leading,5).padding(.trailing,5)
        .padding(.top,(UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.safeAreaInsets.top)! + 10)
    }
}
```

However there is still spacing at the top of the screen:
[image]

I also tried to do this, as suggested in this post [How to move vstack at top of the screen in swiftui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64382144/how-to-move-vstack-at-top-of-the-screen-in-swiftui)

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TopBar()
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't help...
Also if I delete the +10 from the .safeAreaInsets there is still space at the top.

Comment: Is `MyView` your root view? Or is there any parent view?

Comment: @pawello2222 The problem was the rootView, you are right!! Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

May Be padding is the issue. Just remove complex paddings and add the simple padding.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Bar()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


struct Bar: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Community")
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill").font(.headline)
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result in canvas preview]

Comment: You are right, there it added some unnecessary padding at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you remove `.padding(.top,(UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.safeAreaInsets.top)! + 10)` it will be aligned on the top of the screen

Comment: You are right, there it added some unnecessary padding at the top. Thanks!